# Do async in OnEnter React-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

how i could do async in onEnter function?, My case is like below:

My Action:

```
export function getSetupTabTitles(category){
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/api/component/getSetupTabTitles/${category}`,
        {
            headers:{authorization:`Bearer `+localStorage.getItem('laravel_user_token')}
        }).then(response => {
            dispatch({type: GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES,
                payload: response.data.setupTabTitles
            });
        });
    }
}
```

My Second action :

```
export function getPeriod(){
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/api/setup/getPeriod`,
        {
            headers:{authorization:`Bearer `+localStorage.getItem('laravel_user_token')}
        }
        ).then(response => {
                dispatch({type: GET_PERIOD,
                    payload: response.data.activePeriod
                });
            });
    }
}
```

My Function in OnEnter

```
import { store } from '../store/store';
import { getSetupTabTitles } from '../actions/comp.action';
import { getPeriod } from '../actions/setup.action';

export function GET_SetupTabTitles() {
    store.dispatch(getSetupTabTitles('Setup'));
    store.dispatch(getPeriod());
}
```

I need to dispatch them sequentially to get the data before it do transition.

Comment: Semantically, I wouldn't call your data-fetching action `getPeriod` or alike, since you're **setting** values into your store. It doesn't really have anything to do with your question though.  
And what do you mean by **transition**?

Comment: @stinodes i mean before it redirect to the page.

Comment: Is it necessary to do it before transitioning to the next page? It kind of seems like bad design (since you're pretty much blocking the user until the async actions are finished).

Comment: @stinodes i need to load all of that data before it show to user. hmmm, any suggestion?

Comment: Rather than loading it before you show a new page, you should just go to your new page, and in one of its lifecycle-hooks, you can initiate your data-fetch. (meanwhile you can show a spinner or something alike)

Comment: @stinodes ok. thx for your suggestion, could i ask a thing? is react router OnEnter function do dispatch and wait until the data fulfill then redirect to the page, or just do dispatch then redirect to the page even the data is not completely loaded?

Comment: I'd not use the onEnter-function. I'd just do it on `componentDidMount` in your new page.